# Is it possible to access virtual serial ports via Web Serial API?

Tags: serial-port

I seem to only be able to access physical ports. I do want to access virtual ones like ones created with virtual null modem or virtual serial port driver.

Does anyone know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome enumerates serial ports by calling [SetupDiGetClassDevs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw) with [GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SERENUM_BUS_ENUMERATOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-serenum-bus-enumerator). As I discovered when implementing this enumeration logic there are a surprisingly large number of ways to ask Windows for a list of all available COM ports. The advantage of this approach being that it provides device information which can be used to get the human-readable name of the device and USB product identifiers if it is a USB device. It is likely that a virtual COM port driver may be creating the device in a way which prevents it from being discovered this way.

I've created https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1238369 to track this as a Chrome bug. Please comment on whether you are using a different virtual serial port driver than the one mentioned there.

Comment: im trying to connect to my samsung phone via serial port. i got the driver installed and it exposes a serial port but chrome is unable to enumerate the device. this is the device instance path `USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MODEM\7&36E780D2&0&0001` and on device manager it shows up as `SAMSUNG Mobile USB Modem`. any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: this is the class guid `{4d36e96d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get Chrome to see the virtual serial ports using [com0com](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com) on Windows 10 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1110). Chrome connects to the port successfully and it works as expected:

[image: Chrome connects to com0com virtual serial port on Windows 10]

Comment: It doesn't see by default. What are the specific settings on com0com app?